# Can I use Composer instead of Apache to use localhost:8000 etc?

Tags: laravel, apache, server, composer-php

I want to set up the environment for my laravel project to work using a simple method. Apache is so far giving me some trouble in that the home page is not loading and throwing an error.

I have setup an Apache virtual server which is not working as expected.

No codes related to this one.

Set up the environment for my laravel project using

Comment: Please let me know the error you facing with Apache virtual server. Also can you please clear your exact requirements? Do you want to run Laravel over the Virtual Host server?

Comment: I just started using Laravel and I am a newbie. My question actually is "Is Composer acting as a server or not?" "Is it mandatory to use Apache to develop my Laravel application on windows local machine?" Is Composer doing the same work as Apache or are they two different things. I read about these but did not understand much.

Comment: Composer is a package manager (for example to install other PHP packages), Apache is a web server (so it is mainly an HTTP server). They are totally different. You should fix your problem with Apache or use another web server like Nginx or your can also use the built-in PHP server in your CLI